# Can I reference another cell in another sheet using variables?

Tags: excel, vba

Please forgive my absolute lack of knowledge, I normally program in Python and only dabbed my toe in VBA today for one specific purpose, I want to prepare one worksheet that will do the work I need.

In my learning process, I've been trying to write small functions on which I would build my final product. I'm stuck on trying to successfully be able to pass a string/cell as a reference to specific cells in another sheet. Example: I have two sheets called Dog and Cat, and I have their weights in cells A1. I tried writing a function that would would fetch the Cat's weight while being in the Dog's sheet. It goes something like this:

```
Function CatsWeight(ByVal species As String) As Double

    Dim weight As Range

    Set weight = Worksheets(species).Range("A1")
    
    CatsWeight = weight.Value

End Function
```

It just returns #VALUE! error. I also tried to switch it up and call the range as a variable:

```
Function CatsWeight(ByVal cell As Range) As Double

    Dim weight As Range

    Set weight = Worksheets("Cat").cell
    
    CatsWeight = weight.Value

End Function
```

Also doesn't work, but when I call both on "manually" it works:

```
Function CatsWeight() As Double

    Dim weight As Range

    Set weight = Worksheets("Cat").Range("A1")
    
    CatsWeight = weight.Value

End Function
```

What am I doing wrong in my referencing?

Edit because I forgot to say, I call on the functions like this:

=CatsWeight(Cat)

=CatsWeight(A1)

Comment: Does A1 have a number in it? In the first example how are you calling the function?

Comment: Try `=CatsWeight("Cat")`.

Comment: @SJR Sorry, I just edited to add how I call it. Yes, A1 in both sheets has a number.

Comment: @SJR This works, thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked. `species` is a string, hence the need for quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I set up a table with Cat Names & Weights on the Cat Sheet.
I setup a list of cat names on Sheet1.

On sheet1 in the cell to the right of the cats name: CatsWeight()

Here's my function:

```
Function CatsWeight() As Double

Dim rngCell As Range
Set rngCell = Application.Caller

   CatsWeight = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngCell.Offset(0, -1), Range("WeightTable"), 2)
   
End Function
```

HTH